# Open PDF with Microsoft Edge from GPO

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-server-2016, group-policy, gpo

I'm using Policy Management in Windows Server 2016 and I'm working, in particular, with Microsoft Edge policy.

I would like create a policy that block from browser (edge) navigation into disk.

- ex: file://C:/

To do this, I change section [Block access to a list of URLs](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::URLBlocklist) and I add "file://*"

All works correctly... but... I need to open my pdf with Edge, and this policy block everything.

I tried to implement [Define a list of allowed URLs](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::URLAllowlist) and I added "file://*.pdf", but it isn't works

Somebody have any suggest?

PS: any improvement in the question is welcome (english - technical lexicon - etc..)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc: [Filter format for URL list-based policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmmore-url-list-filter%20format), I think this configuration rule cannot achieve the function similar to regular expressions to meet your requirements. It only allows to match all or a single path.

And if you use a browser to navigate to `file://URLs`, there are some security risks, so I don't recommend you to do this. For more details, you could read this article about [Restrictions on File Urls](https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/);

Comment: What is your suggest?

Comment: What I mean is that you can’t block/allow specific file types through this GPO setting, it only works with a specific file, like: `file://C:\example.pdf`. Or block/allow all files: `file://*`